# How to install Anaconda python for all users?

Tags: python, anaconda

[Anaconda python distribution](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) is very convenient to deploy scientific computing env (SCE) and switch python versions as you want. By default, the installation will locate python into `~/anaconda` and the SCE can only benefit the local user.

But what I need is to provide a complete SCE wit Anaconda while masking the system-wide python version, because my cluster is running Spark and provides services for multiple users in our team. Is it possible with current Anaconda version?

Xiaming

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The installer lets you install anywhere. You can install it to a global location, like `/opt/anaconda`.

Comment: Yeah. Thats it. All users can access this global path.

Comment: How would each user set this as their default python path?

Comment: Each user would need to add it to their PATH in their bash profile.

Comment: You can also modify PATH in `/etc/profile`, which is executed for all users.

Comment: @becko thanks, updating: `sudo mkdir /opt/anaconda && sudo chmod ugo+w /opt/anaconda` then you can specify the path during installation to `/opt/anaconda/anaconda3`

Answer (score 8):

Add the anaconda PATH to `/etc/profile`:

**for anaconda 2 :**

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/anaconda/bin
```

**for anaconda 3 :**

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/anaconda3/bin
```

**and then :**

```
source /etc/profile
```

Comment: Seems like it should go in `/etc/environment`?

Comment: It s the same thing

Comment: Well, seems `/etc/environment` is for applications that aren't shell related.  I ended up making a `conda.sh` in `/etc/profile.d/`.  But that adds everything in '*/anaconda/bin*` to the path which seems excessive.  We'll see...

Comment: this does not seem to be working for me. I'm getting really strange behavior though - as myself I can still do `conda activate` and everything seems fine, but if I try to run a script that calls `conda activate` I get ye olde error `CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.`

Comment: @szeitlin did you check if the PATH is correctly added to you `/etc/profile`?

Comment: Tried that, `conda activate` was working, but it broke some other stuff in my path, so I had to undo it.

Comment: How is that supposed to work? `$HOME/anaconda/bin` is different for each user, and anaconda should be installed once on the system.

Answer (score 3):

Anaconda Cluster from Continuum that addresses these issues.  Check out https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda-scale/

Comment: the anaconda-cluster url links to 'https://www.continuum.io/why-anaconda' now - I guess they've changed it's name?

Comment: It's actually been updated again - there are new links. Now called Anaconda Scale https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda-scale/

Comment: Thank you @datakid.  Updated yet again.

Answer (score 3):

You definitely need to install to a path which is accessible from all users. `/opt/YOUR_CONDA_DISTRIB_NAME` is a good candidate.

However you also have to add `conda` path which automatically happens when you add the following shell script to other users' `.bashrc` files. You can find the shell script in the root user's `.bashrc` file. For the record, I bring it here:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/opt/YOUR_CONDA_DISTRIB_NAME/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/opt/YOUR_CONDA_DISTRIB_NAME/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/opt/YOUR_CONDA_DISTRIB_NAME/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/opt/YOUR_CONDA_DISTRIB_NAME/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

P.S. a few common names which Anaconda commonly uses for `YOUR_CONDA_DISTRIB_NAME`:

- `anaconda`
- `anaconda3`
- `miniconda`
- `miniconda3`

Answer (score 1):

You can also let any user who needs conda run the `conda init` command to automatically let conda update their .bashrc so they will be able to use the conda environment. For example in linux if anaconda is installed in /opt/anaconda3:

```
$ /opt/anaconda3/bin/conda init
no change     /opt/anaconda3/condabin/conda
no change     /opt/anaconda3/bin/conda
no change     /opt/anaconda3/bin/conda-env
no change     /opt/anaconda3/bin/activate
no change     /opt/anaconda3/bin/deactivate
no change     /opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
no change     /opt/anaconda3/etc/fish/conf.d/conda.fish
no change     /opt/anaconda3/shell/condabin/Conda.psm1
no change     /opt/anaconda3/shell/condabin/conda-hook.ps1
no change     /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xontrib/conda.xsh
no change     /opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.csh
modified      /home/my.userid/.bashrc

==> For changes to take effect, close and re-open your current shell. <==
```